# Calculating end point co-ordinates

Tags: java, linear-algebra

I am working on a project involving co-ordinates. I have been working on this project for a while now and I currently have it so the user enters two co-ordinates and a scale factor and it calculates things such as the slope of the line, the length, Y-intercept etc. One of the things I would like to do is calculate and output the end point co-ordinates after the line has been multiplied by the scale factor. 
For example if the user sets the following co-ordinates:

```
x = (3, 5)
y = (6, 8)

And:

Scale factor: 3

The user would get the following output:

Slope: 1.00
Length: 4.24
Y-Intercept: 2.00
Equation: y = 1.00x + 2.00
Length After Scaling: 12.73
```

Multiplying by the scale factor would make the line length would go from `4.24` to `12.73`. How do I calculate the co-ordinates of the end point?

Many thanks!

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Java programming and is better suited for [`MathStackExchange`](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: New y's first coordinate = `3 + (6-3)/4.24*12.73` (I'm assuming x and y are points as opposed to coordinates, your syntax is confusing), but the question doesn't really fit on [so] as it's not really about programming.

Comment: How is the line scaled? Is the center immobile? One of the end points? Without this information, the question is meaningless.

Comment: @JimGarrison It does say "How do I calculate the co-ordinates of **the end point**" (not end points), thus presumably one point is fixed, or a simple typing error. Actually reading the question again, I agree that this is unclear, that's the assumption my previous comment made.

Answer (score 1):

Building off Dukeling's comment:

`scaledX = x1 + ((x2-x1)*scaledLength)/length`

`scaledY = y1 + ((y2-y1)*scaledLength)/length`

Answer (score 1):

You want the new point to lie on the same line as the starting point. You already have the equation for this line and thus the equation for any point on this line. It will be as follows with p3 being the new endpoint:

[image]

Inserting gives p3 = [12, 14] on the plusside.

You will generally get a quadratic equation to solve because the fourth line won't be nicely summable (a+2-5 happens to be the same as (a-3)).